# How to make Netbeans show variable names like IntelliJ?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Is there a plugin or function to enable to make Netbeans show the variable names?

[image: pretty variable names]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **ALT+SHIFT+1** to bring up the variable viewer.